# Missing data points in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am extremely new to python and coding in general.  I have some data in 1 minute intervals which is potentially missing some times.  I would like to fill in the missing time and a NaN value for the corresponding data point.  This is what I have thus far and it is filling in NaN for all data points instead of just the missing.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data3.csv", index_col="DateTime")
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("11-1-2014 12:00:00", "11-1-2014 12:10:00", freq="1min"), fill_value="NaN")
df.to_csv("test3.csv")
```

**File I am reading**

```
                NSERC_CB04_A0401
DateTime                        
11/1/2014 0:00          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:01          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:02          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:03          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:04          1.118503
11/1/2014 0:05          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:06          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:07          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:09          1.121889
11/1/2014 0:10          1.121889
```

**File I am writing**

```
                               NSERC_CB04_A0401
2014-11-01 12:00:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:01:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:02:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:03:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:04:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:05:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:06:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:07:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:08:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:09:00              NaN
2014-11-01 12:10:00              NaN
```

**What I want:**

```
                    NSERC_CB04_A0401
    DateTime                        
    11/1/2014 0:00          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:01          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:02          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:03          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:04          1.118503
    11/1/2014 0:05          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:06          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:07          1.121889
2014-11-01 12:08:00              NaN
    11/1/2014 0:09          1.121889
    11/1/2014 0:10          1.121889
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem you are new in coding and in python!

You need add parameter `parse_dates=True` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for convert `index` to `DatetimIndex` first and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - start time from `11-1-2014 12:00:00` is changed to `11-1-2014 00:00:00` for matching, similar end time.

Also string `NaN` is not missing value, you need `np.nan` what is default value for missing data in `reindex`.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data3.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True)

df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("11-1-2014 00:00:00", "11-1-2014 00:10:00", freq="1min"))
print (df)
                     NSERC_CB04_A0401
2014-11-01 00:00:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:01:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:02:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:03:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:04:00          1.118503
2014-11-01 00:05:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:06:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:07:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:08:00               NaN
2014-11-01 00:09:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:10:00          1.121889
```

More general solution is `reindex` by `min` and `max` `datetime`, but it depends of your data:

```
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1min"))
print (df)
                     NSERC_CB04_A0401
2014-11-01 00:00:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:01:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:02:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:03:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:04:00          1.118503
2014-11-01 00:05:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:06:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:07:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:08:00               NaN
2014-11-01 00:09:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:10:00          1.121889
```

If duplicates in index solution is [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum` - also se [resample docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling):

```
print (df)
                     NSERC_CB04_A0401
DateTime                             
2014-11-01 00:00:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:01:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:02:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:03:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:04:00          1.118503
2014-11-01 00:05:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:06:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:07:00          1.121889 <- duplicates index
2014-11-01 00:07:00          1.121889 <- duplicates index
2014-11-01 00:09:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:10:00          1.121889

df = df.resample('1min').mean()
print (df)
                     NSERC_CB04_A0401
DateTime                             
2014-11-01 00:00:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:01:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:02:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:03:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:04:00          1.118503
2014-11-01 00:05:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:06:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:07:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:08:00               NaN
2014-11-01 00:09:00          1.121889
2014-11-01 00:10:00          1.121889
```

Comment: Thank you that works if I have just the 2 columns.  When try it for my code with 12 columns I get an error "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: Thank you again really helpful.  One last question how would I go about using np.nan to give a NaN value in missing data rows?  Right now I am just getting an empty row instead of a NaN.

Comment: I dont understand do you get instead NaN values nothing, empty string?

Comment: yes it is filling in the missing time, but giving empty rows instead of NaN.

Comment: It is interesting, I have no idea what can be problem.

Comment: Ok, if still problem and your data are not confidental, you can send me your csv to my email in profile and tomorrow I try find solution. It seems some problem is in your real data.